# Convert Event based pattern to async CTP pattern

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, async-await

```
  _fbClient.GetCompleted += new EventHandler<FacebookApiEventArgs>(OnFetchPageNotification);
  _fbClient.GetAsync(_kNotificationPath, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "access_token", _kPageAccessToken } });
```

How to convert above code into awaitable code in wp7:

```
 object = await _fbClient.GetAsync(_kNotificationPath, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "access_token", _kPageAccessToken } });
```

I have CTP Installed and task parallel library also.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Async CTP came with a document that describes how to adapt each existing pattern to the Task Based Async pattern. It says that the Event based one is more variable, but does give one example:

```
public static Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(Uri url)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    var wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s,e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
        else if (e.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        else tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
    };
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(url);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Where the original function that's being wrapped is `DownloadStringAsync`, the parameters match the parameters being passed to this function, and `DownloadStringCompleted` is the event that is being monitored.

---

(The same document appears to be downloadable [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=19957) - the above sample (and more description) are from "Tasks and the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)")

Comment: I wonder if with this pattern you would need to unsubscribe from the `DownloadStringCompleted` event to avoid a memory leak or if the lambda is just a loose object on the heap.

Comment: @FilipSkakun - only just noticed your comment, so apologies for the delay in responding. You'll notice that the event is on the `wc` object which itself looks like it may be garbage collected soon. Whatever is happening inside `DownloadStringAsync` is presumably keeping the `wc` object alive enough that the event handler is even *called*. But once that's done, `wc` is surely eligible for garbage collection, and so, therefore, should be the delegate that was added to the event.

Comment: Just curious, why does it have to be a static method? Could we just write it as a private method?

Comment: @frostshoxx - it doesn't "have" to be a static method. But given that the above code is self-contained and clearly doesn't depend on any instance state of whatever class it's contained in, static seems sensible. public/private is a separate choice and yes, it could easy be private if that was applicable. However, I was just copying an existing code sample and it was probably intended to end up in a "Utility" style class for helper functions.