# Working with Background File Transfer with Task.Wait()

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, backgroundworker, async-await

I am working with a 3rd party library that is event based. I am really only interested in calling a library method and knowing when the library has finished. Pretty much like here: [Convert Event based pattern to async CTP pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853445/convert-event-based-pattern-to-async-ctp-pattern/12853892#12853892)

The thing is that the library seems to use Windows Phone's `Background File Transfer` to do its job.

My symptom is that the library's completion handler is called only after my [Task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has timed out.

I tried to search for some docs about running Background File Transfer in the ThreadPool (as I assume in my async code, that's where the library is running), but couldn't really find any information. So could my issue (that completion handler is called only after timeout) be that Background File Transfer code shouldn't run in the ThreadPool?

Any ideas what a good approach for this kind of problem would be?

Comment: Apparently, you're blocking the UI thread and its message pump with `Task.Wait`, so the completion event doesn't have a chance to get fired properly. Use `await task` instead and make the whole chain of calls `async`.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I am following this pattern here, which does not use async/await: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853445/convert-event-based-pattern-to-async-ctp-pattern/12853892#12853892

Comment: The pattern you linked is correct. It doesn't use `async/await` but it doesn't use `Task.Wait()` either. It returns a `Task` object, and you're expected to `await` on that task asynchrnously, instead of blocking with `task.Wait()`. Feel free to post more of your relevant code, and we may help fixing it. To understand the problem better, read this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and pinpointing to my misunderstanding. I totally understand my issue now. And feel free to post your comment as an answer, and I will mark it as an answer to this question.

Comment: No problem, I've posted an answer with some additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you linked is correct. It doesn't use `async/await` but it doesn't use `Task.Wait()` either. It returns a `Task` object, and you're expected to `await` on that task asynchronously. Which means, the code after `await task` will be asynchronously invoked by the Task Scheduler when the task has reached the complete (faulted, cancelled) state.

Otherwise, you're blocking the UI thread and its message pump with the synchronous `Task.Wait()` call, so the completion event doesn't have a chance to get fired properly.

To understand this issue better, here is a very good read: [Don't Block on Async](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

To correct your code, you'd have to make the whole chain of calls `async`, up to the root, which in a UI app is usually an event handler. E.g.:

```cs
// note, "async void" is normally only good for async event handler
async void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var task = DownloadStringAsync("http://example.com"); // for example 
        // Wrong: task.Wait();      
        await task;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

On a side note, now you've got other things to worry about. The UI is not blocked any more, while the asynchronous operation is still in progress. So, your user may click the `Test` button again, and you're suddenly having two pending async operations. You should account for such scenario (it's been widely discussed here on SO as well).

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This indeed was my issue.