# Is this REALLY async email AND best practice?

Tags: c#, .net, email, asynchronous, task

I am trying to learn and master ASYNC and AWAIT but it is not clear if what I do is the right thing at then end.. I mean the code works and I took two browsers/instances of the same form and click, well, almost at the same time and everything went OK. I received 2 emails but is it the right way to do it? and does it really gives a plus value to do it async instead of sync...

This is my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
       bla bla do some sync simple stuffs etc...
       ...
       await Task.Run(() => Utility.MailUtility.SendEmail(user.Email, user.To, msg, subj));
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

and then the mailing code looks like this, as per a sample code taken from stackoverflow:

```
    public static async Task SendEmail(params etc...) 
    {
        await SendMailForTemplateID(params etc...);
    }

    private static Task SendMailForTemplateID(params etc...)
    {


            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                //SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPHost"]);
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("localhost"); // for test purpose only
                mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
                mail.To.Add(to);
                mail.Subject = GetSubjectForTemplateId(templateID, extraMsg, dataInfo, fromName, toName, isFr);
                mail.Body = GetBodyForTemplateId(templateID, extraMsg, dataInfo, fromName, toName, isFr);
                mail.IsBodyHtml = false; 
                SmtpServer.Port = 81; // for test purpose only
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                    (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CredentialUser"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CredentialPassword"]);

                bool result;
                bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSSL"], out result);
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = result;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);

                //* make sure we leave nothing in memory
                message.Dispose();
                mail.Dispose();
                SmtpServer.Dispose();


            });

            return task;

       }
```

---

I am sorry guys but I don't know how to put line return (enter) between my replies. Is It possible? nway, regarding ASYNC-EMAIL best practice.

My new version of code looks like this, it works more simple coding but is it right? I mean no new threads, does it give a plus value VS sync sendmail methods etc...

I call it in a MVC action. The code:

```
     do stuff...
     await Utility.MailUtility.SendMailForTemplateID(params);
     do stuff...

   public static async Task SendMailForTemplateID(params...)
    {
        try
        {
            email code etc...

            await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail);

            mail.Dispose();
            smtpClient.Dispose();


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Log ex
        }
    }
```

Comment: No. You're creating threads, that is going to make it use more CPU, not less. Your goal is to only `await` the IO operations. Best practice would be to use the `SendMailAsync` method that already exists on the `SmtpClient` class. That will cause the IO to `await`, but not create new threads.

Comment: Should also mention you call `Task.Factory.StartNew` which creates a thread, then you call `Task.Run` which creates a thread. You're executing this across 3 threads when you only need 1. (`Task.Run` calls `Task.Factory.StartNew`)

Answer (score 4):

No, wrapping async calls into `Task.Run` is wrong way of writing `async`/`await` code.

One particular problem with your current code is `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` start new threads to execute operation - so code starts 2 extra threads to execute operation.

Correct way - remove all `Task.Run`/`Task.Factory.StartNew` calls and `await` asynchronous calls all the way down. In your case [`SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx) should be used at lowest level instead of `SmtpServer.Send(mail);`.

In more generic case when there is no Task-based API but there is some alternative asynchronous APIs (like event-based [`SmtpClient.SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb90y5w7(v=vs.110).aspx) ) you may need to provide wrapping helper methods to transform such calls to Task-based `async` methods. Some approaches shown in [Convert Event based pattern to async CTP pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853445/convert-event-based-pattern-to-async-ctp-pattern)

---

Approximate code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
   ...
   await Utility.MailUtility.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, user.To, msg, subj));
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

// No need to add `async` here as there is no `await` inside,
// possibly can be removed altogether.
public static Task SendEmailAsync(params etc...) 
{
    return SendMailForTemplateID(params etc...);
}

private async static Task SendMailForTemplateID(params etc...)
{
     // not Task.Run / Task.Factory.StartNew

     using (MailMessage message = ... )
     using (SmtpClient smtp = ....)
     {
            .... // setup message/smtp

            await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail); // Task-based Send
     }
     // no need to return anything for `Task` (essentially `void`) method 
   }
```

Comment: There is already a task based async method on `SmtpClient` as I mentioned in my comment, `SendMailAsync`. No wrapping needed.

Comment: It's also worth noting that using `Task.Run` in ASP.Net is a bad practice. Read up on some articles that Stephen Cleary has written on his blog: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Comment: @dman2306 - thanks - missed that one - inlined to the answer.

Comment: @Cameron there are a lot of things that can be mentioned - I'm not sure all warnings (like "don't `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in ASP.Net) should be added into answer. I think your comment is perfectly is good way to do so.

Comment: If I get it right i need to call this with await, 1. await Utility.MailUtility.SendMailForTemplateID(params...); 2.      public static async Task SendMailForTemplateID(params..)
        {
            try
            {

               ... email code etc...

                await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail);

                mail.Dispose();
                smtpClient.Dispose();


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Log ex
            }
        }

Comment: @MartinMightyMartLauzon yes. I'll edit my answer to show that.

Comment: Now I have the coding right, BUT, Id would really want to know what are the ADVANTAGES? Is it better user wise? execution time wise? or simply to let the user do other stuff on the site and who cares that email is in the inbox of the recipient in 2 sec, 20 seconds or 3 minutes?

Comment: @MartinMightyMartLauzon When you're waiting for socket IO to complete, instead of blocking the thread, you return it to the thread pool so it can serve other requests.

Comment: @MartinMightyMartLauzon `async` in ASP.Net environment frees up threads for more requests to be handled. There are plenty of articles discussing that - you can start from SO questions found by https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+async+useful